# PHP: replace variable values within string

Tags: php, arrays, replace, str-replace

I am pretty new to PHP and hope someone here can help me with this:

I have a variable string that looks like the following, containing either nothing OR a series of words, separated with comma and space.

**Example:**

```
item1, item2, item3
```

What would be the best / fastest way to replace the single items in this string by adding an img tag with the same item name as the source + remove the commas ?

**The above example should then look as follows:**

```
item1 <img src="item1.png" alt="" /> item2 <img src="item2.png" alt="" /> item3 <img src="item3.png" alt="" />
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: A one-liner: `echo implode("\n", array_map(function($v) {return '<img src="'.trim($v).'png" alt="" />'; }, explode(',', $str)));`

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/(\w+),?\s*/', '<img src="${1}.png" alt="" /> ', $str);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a 1-liner, but since you're new to PHP, lets just make it clear.

First split the string to get an array of the different items.

```
$itemsStr = "item1, item2, item3";  // input string
$items = explode(", ", $itemsStr);  // Gets an array of items
```

Now traverse the items array and add the string for each item:

```
foreach($items as $key => $val)
{
    $items[$key] = $item . "<img src='$item.png' alt='' /> ";
}

$output = implode(" ", $items);
```

Comment: nice one @Joshua Kissoon

Answer (score 1):

This [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should do it:

```
$in = 'item1, item2, item3';
$out = preg_replace('/( ?([^,]+)),?/', '$1 <img src="$2.png" alt="" />', $in);
```

`$out` then is:

```
item1 <img src="item1.png" alt="" /> item2 <img src="item2.png" alt="" /> item3 <img src="item3.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would the number change here so that the img source is item1.png or item2.png or item3.png ?